# log4j immediateFlush truncate line

Tags: log4j2

i try to use log4j in asynchronous mode, it works but when it writes the log it doesn't end the line. A line potion is to remain in memory until the next writing. Is there a configuration to force it to end a line if it starts writing it

log4j config :

```
<RollingFile name="ordsLogger"
                         fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/ords_sante.log"
                         immediateFlush="true" complete="true"
                         filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/ords_sante-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>|%msg%n
            </pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <PatternLayout pattern="..." charset="UTF-8"/>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
        </Policies>
        <!-- Max 10 files will be created everyday -->
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10">
            <Delete basePath="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/" maxDepth="10">
                <!-- Delete all files older than 30 days -->
                <IfLastModified age="30d" />
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
```

the goal is for the log file to be read by filebeat, so the line must be completed

Comment: Can you add your configuration to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try settings `bufferedIo` to `false` in your `RollingFile` element as it's set to `true` by default for all `OutputStream`-based appenders. You should also set `bufferSize` to 0 to prevent a warning log message, too, as the default buffer size is non-zero (having a non-zero buffer size with buffering disabled emits a warning).

Edit: it appears as though the `immediateFlush` option in `RollingFileAppender` isn't even used! We have ourselves a bug: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/2025